# Performing a task in x seconds efficiently in Ruby

Tags: multithreading, sinatra

In my Sinatra application I'd like a method to be called when a user visits a specific URL then, x seconds later (without keeping the HTTP stream open), a different method should be called.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Ruby Threads](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html):

```
second_thread = Thread.new() do
    sleep 10 # Let's only execute this after 10 seconds
    ... do processing here
end

second_thread.join()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling this was going to be a way of dealing with this problem. I had thought it wouldn't be very efficient though (I know threads can be a little restrictive - especially when one thread requires much more processor time than another - I read somewhere about Fibers being more useful?) but I'm happy to accept this as the best answer if no-one offers reasons why this isn't a good method!

Comment: Fibers might indeed be a good way to go. I just listed threads as I've  done something similar that turned out to work pretty well.